# Electrical properties of 2D materials

Tags: materials, electricity

This is regarding to the newly-discovered 2-D materials that can support electron flow, such as phosphorene and transition metal dichalcogenides. How do they conduct electricity?

I also read that their electric properties change with the number of layers. For example, the band gap of black phosphorus changes from 0 - 2 eV with the number of layers. Why is this so?